# Cloudformation & Parameter Store: How to select parameter for the environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-systems-manager

I want to read the URL of my database from parameter store in my CloudFormation template. This is easy enough for a single URL, but I can't figure out how to change the URL with different environments.

I have four environments (development, integration, pre-production and production) and their details are stored on four different paths in Parameter Store:

```
/database/dev/url
/database/int/url
/database/ppe/url
/database/prod/url
```

I now want to pick the correct Database URL when deploying via CloudFormation. How can I do this?

```yaml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - int
      - ppe
      - prod
  DatabaseUrl:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    # Obviously the '+' operator here won't work - so what do I do?
    Default: '/database/' + Environment + '/url'
```

Comment: If you can't find a better solution, you can always pre-process the template and fill in the environment in all the SSM parameters.

Comment: Would appreciate if the submitter identified the answer to his question.

Answer (score 7):

This feature isn't as neat as one would wish. You have to actually pass name/path of each parameter that you want to look up from the parameter store.

Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: Example

Parameters:

  BucketNameSuffix:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /example/dev/BucketNameSuffix

Resources:

  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub parameter-store-example-${BucketNameSuffix}
```

If you don't pass any parameters to the template, `BucketNameSuffix` will be populated with the value stored at `/example/dev/BucketNameSuffix`. If you want to use, say, a `prod` value (pointed to by `/example/prod/BucketNameSuffix`), then you should specify value for parameter `BucketNameSuffix`, but instead of passing the actual value you should pass the alternative name of the parameter to use, so you'd pass `/example/prod/BucketNameSuffix`.

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name example-dev \
--template-body file://./example-stack.yml

aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name example-prod \
--template-body file://./example-stack.yml \
--parameters ParameterKey=BucketNameSuffix,ParameterValue=/example/prod/BucketNameSuffix
```

A not so great AWS blog post on this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Because passing million meaningless parameters seems stupid, I might actually generate an environment-specific template and set the right `Default:` in the generated template so for `prod` environment `Default` would be `/example/prod/BucketNameSuffix` and then I can update the `prod` stack without passing any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can populate CloudFormation templates with parameters stored in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store using [Dynamic References](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html)

In this contrived example we make two lookups using `resolve:ssm` and replace the environment using [`!Join`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) and [`!Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: prod
    AllowedValues:
      - prod
      - staging
Resources:
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        Image: !Join
          - ''
          -   - 'docker.io/bitnami/redis@'
              - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/app/${Environment}/digest-sha/redis}}'
        Environment:
          - Name: DB_HOST
            Value: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/app/${Environment}/db-host}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Fn::Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) here.

Here is some pseudo code.

You will have to take Environment as an parameter, which you are already doing.

Creating the required string in the resources where DatabaseUrl is required.

```
Resources :
  Instance :
    Type : 'AWS::Some::Resource'
    Properties :
       DatabaseURL : !Join [ "", [ "/database/", !Ref "Environment" , "/url ] ]
```

Hope this helps.

Note: You cannot assign value to a Parameter dynamically using some computation logic. All the values for defined parameters should be given as Input.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. You would need to do this on  the Default of BucketNameSuffix, but that is not allowed by CloudFormation :(

Answer (score 0):

I like [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab2c21c28c56c11), which is much cleaner and easy to read.

```
!Sub "/database/${Environment}/url"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. You would need to do this on  the Default of BucketNameSuffix, but that is not allowed by CloudFormation :(

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck into the same problem, below are my findings:

1. We can compose values and descriptions while writing into the SSM Parameter Store from CloudFormation like below :

   ```
   LambdaARN:
     Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
     Properties:
       Type: String
       Description: !Sub "Lambda ARN from ${AWS::StackName}"
       Name: !Sub "/secure/${InstallationId}/${AWS::StackName}/lambda-function-arn"
       Value: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
   ```
2. We can not compose values/defaults to looking for in SSM Parameter Store. Like below:

   ```
   Parameters:
   ...
     LambdaARN:
       Type: Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
       Value: !Sub "/secure/${InstallationId}/teststack/lambda-function-arn"
   ```

This is not allowed as per AWS Documentation[1]. Both(Sub/Join) Functions won't work. Following is the error which I was getting:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet
> operation: Template format error: Every Default member must be a
> string.

3. Composing and passing values while creating stacks can be done like this:

   ```
   Parameters:
   ...
     LambdaARN:
       Type: Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
   ....

   $ aws cloudformation deploy --template-file cfn.yml --stack-name mystack  --parameter-overrides 'LambdaARN=/secure/devtest/teststack/lambda_function-arn'
   ```
4. If you add your custom tags while putting the values in the Parameter Store, it will overwrite the default tags added by CFN.

Default Tags:

```
- aws:cloudformation:stack-id
- aws:cloudformation:stack-name
- aws:cloudformation:logical-id
```

5. Every time we update the values in parameter store, it creates a new version, which is beneficial when we are using *DynamicResolvers*, this can serve as a solution to the problem in the question like

> {{ resolve:ssm:/my/value:1}}

The last field is the version. Where different versions can point to different environments.

6. We are using versions with the parameters, and adding the labels to them[2], this can't be done via CFN[3], only possible way via CLI or AWS Console. This is AWS's way of handling multiple environments.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-labels.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html